# Repeatable regex pattern in Google Forms field validation

Tags: regex, google-forms

I'm new to regular expression and I've got an issue in google forms field validation after a few times trying to find the answer. Here's my current condition ([expression in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GWDyRQ/1)):

```
[A-Z].*\s[0-9,].+\|$
```

The expected answer should be: `Peter 50|Alex 20|`

But when the respondent fills in the field something like `Peter 50|Alex|` (without the number), it's also a match. How can I force respondents to specify the names and their corresponding numbers in a manner that following a pattern?

Specifically, it should be: `Name1 number1|Name2 number2|Name3 number3|Name4 number4|...`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `.+` matches too much, as the `.` matches any character.

You can repeat the matches with a pipe at the end, and start with an uppercase char [A-Z].

```
^(?:[A-Z]\w*\s[0-9]+\|)+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Z]\w*` Match an uppercase char A-Z and optional word characters
  - `\s[0-9]+\|` Match a whitspace char and 1+ digits and `|`
- `)+` Close the group and repeat 1+ times to match multiple occurrences
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SYup0z/1)

If you have names that can contain any non whitespace char, and you meant to match digits with an optional decimal part according to the comma:

```
^(?:[A-Z][^\s|]*\s[0-9]+(?:,\d+)?\|)+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Z][^\s|]*` Match an uppercase char A-Z followed by 0+ times any non whitespace char except `|`
  - `\s[0-9]+(?:,\d+)?\|` Match a whitespace char, 1+ digits and an optional decimal part followed by `|`
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pki7mt/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
^(?:\p{L}+\s\d+\|)+$
```

See the [RE2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WdJ3PD/2) (Google Forms uses [RE2 regex flavor](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\p{L}+` - one or more letters
  - `\s` - a whitespace (use `\s+` to allow one or more whitespaces)
  - `\d+` - one or more digits
- `)+` - end of the group, repeat one or more times
- `$` - end of string.
- `\|$`